# How to copy dll from GAC

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

VS 2005

I have dll conflict .. I need to add Microsoft.Data.SqlXml Version 9.0.242.0 dll to my Project.  This dll is shipped along with VS 2005 / SQL Express Edition. When i installed VS 2005 on my computer, i skipped installing Express Edition. Because, i already  have SQL 2008 Edition on my computer.

Now my project is not building as because of this dll. I installed SQLEXP.exe for 2005 version.. but still it doesn't helped me.

Now, i am trying to copy this .dll from another computer to  my computer. So how should i copy the .dll without uninstalling ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to copy a DLL from the GAC using the command line.  Just navigate to the folder (C:\Windows\Assembly) and take it, although the structure of the folder is different, it's quite intuitive.

This [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CopyDllFromGac.aspx) has quite a few images and explanations.

Comment: -u shows uninstall, my concern .. is , from where copying this dll is actually application is working well ..! if i uninstalled .. it should not stop the application

Comment: Please read the article, you don't uninstall you can copy and paste the dll without removing it.